# How to call a list declared in VB.net from aspx

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I'm trying to build a website ASP.net with vb.net. And I'm trying to access the declared list in VB.net from ASPX page using java script but unfortunately I can't.

Here is my back end code

```
  Protected CustomerRoleTypes As New List(Of CustomerRoleType)
  CustomerRoleTypes.Add("Junior")

     function ValidateRoleType() {
        const customerRoleTypes = "<%: string.Concat(",",CustomerRoleTypes )%>"; // not getting any values here
        const restrictedCustomerRoles = customerRoleTypes.split(",");
        
        return true;
    }
```

How can I access the list variable from javascript function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, you should consider setting up a web method, and then doing a ajax call from client js code. That is the "normal" way of doing such things.

However, you can certainly use a client side "server" expression as your sample attempts.

Your code behind on the web page?

Well, I don't know, see, nor have your class and the list.

But, you can do it this way:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

End Sub

Public Function MyFriendList() As String


    Dim MyCoolFriends As New List(Of Person)

    ' add two people to the cool friends list

    Dim OnePerson As New Person

    OnePerson.FirstName = "Clark"
    OnePerson.LastName = "Kent"
    MyCoolFriends.Add(OnePerson)

    OnePerson = New Person
    OnePerson.FirstName = "Bruce"
    OnePerson.LastName = "Wayne"
    MyCoolFriends.Add(OnePerson)

    Dim sResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyCoolFriends)

    Return sResult


End Function

Class Person
    Public FirstName As String
    Public LastName As String
End Class
```

So, you can then return that "list" of people (or in your case role types).

Then in your markup, you can use the expression like you have, say this:

Lets for testing just drop in a button we click, and show the first person in our list.

```
        <asp:Button ID="cmdShow" runat="server" Text="Show cool friends"
            OnClientClick="ShowFriendsTest();return false"  />

        <script>

            function ShowFriendsTest() {

                MyFriendsRaw = '<%= MyFriendList() %>'
                MyFriends = JSON.parse(MyFriendsRaw)
                // show first person in list
                OnePerson = MyFriends[0]
                alert(OnePerson.FirstName + ' ' + OnePerson.LastName)                    
            }

        </script>
```

When we run the above, we see this:

[image]

The above assumes you using some kind of serializer.

I am using newtonsoft's json (you can use nuget to install if  you don't have).